# How to draw random number from a Cauchy Distribution in Matlab

Tags: matlab, random, distribution

I know random number can be drawn from a `Normal Distribution` as follows

```
normrnd(mu, sd)
```

where `mu=mean` and `sd=standard deviation`

But how can we draw a random number from `Cauchy Distribution` with given `location parameter` and `scale parameter`, as there is no built-in function available in matlab. For more information about Cauchy Distribution see [Link1](http://www.math.wm.edu/~leemis/chart/UDR/PDFs/Cauchy.pdf) and [Link2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution).

Comment: Without knowing anything else about this distribution, I'd suggest [inverse transform sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling).

Comment: Does this help? https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/work-with-the-cauchy-distribution-using-the-t-location-scale-distribution.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always write your own function, if you know the cdf.

```
function x = cauchy_dist(location_parameter, scale_parameter)
p_cdf = rand(); %uniform random from 0->1, since cdf by definition 0->1
x = location_parameter + scale_parameter*tan(pi*(p_cdf-0.5)); %solve cdf eqn for x
```

Comment: with this one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution
i find this sollution
x = location_parameter + scale_parameter*tan(pi*(p_cdf-0.5));

Comment: Thanks, Gelliant -- too much reliance on wolfram alpha

Comment: Yours works as well and might be faster too.
x = location_parameter - scale_parameter./tan(pi*p_cdf); I just don't understand why it's the same.

Comment: It's because `tan(anything - pi/2)` = `- 1/tan(anything)`

Answer (score 0):

From the explanation given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/484395/how-to-generate-a-cauchy-random-variable), you can get a Cauchy distributed random number from an uniform random number using the following transformation:

```
r = tan(pi*(rand()-0.5))
```